# How to assign a NULL value to an OID?

Tags: snmp

I have to make the code portable to work on 2 different devices where the length of the OID is just different by 1 byte. Therefore I am reusing the same struct to send the OIDs.

For device #1 I have

```
  MIB[0]=0x2b
  MIB[1]=0x06
  MIB[2]=0x01
  MIB[3]=0x02
  MIB[4]=0x01
  MIB[5]=0x02    
  MIB[6]=0x02
  MIB[7]=0x01
  MIB[8]=0x08
  MIB[9]=0xA0
  MIB[10]=0x00
```

For device #2 I have

```
  MIB[0]=0x2b
  MIB[1]=0x06
  MIB[2]=0x01
  MIB[3]=0x02
  MIB[4]=0x01
  MIB[5]=0x02    
  MIB[6]=0x02
  MIB[7]=0x01
  MIB[8]=0x08
  MIB[9]=0x01
  MIB[10]=???
```

How do I assign MIB[10] to be NULL, so that the OID that is sent will be 1.3.6.1.2.1.8.1 instead of 1.3.6.1.2.1.8.1.**0** by sending MIB[10] = 0x00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no representation for end-of-OID in the data; the length is encoded in the ASN.1 field used to transfer the OID, and this field needs to be replicated along with the OID (especially as you are using the serialized form anyway).